# Firebase Analytics keeps causing errors in Android, why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

After I installed Firebase Analytics in my Android app, I keep getting the following error and crash of the app.

```
10-03 19:08:03.917 17740-17759/******* E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct
(declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/data/********/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.0.0_4ac10bd34145eacbd51560cb14cd41a784d8c1aa-classes.dex): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea why and what causes this error?

Comment: Post your build.gradle file.  Looks like you are using version 9.0.0.  That's very old.  Current is 9.6.1.

Comment: +1 for build.graddle file. It looks like you are using mismatching versions of firebase/google play service components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something was wrong in the documentation. The instructions didn't tell me this extra step.

I was missing a dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```

In the support docs, however it is clearly mentioned. I added it and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

What Firebase version are you using? Try to update it to latest version, 9.6

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases